# Pentaho reporting

Tags: reporting, pentaho, business-intelligence

I have been working on a projet about data integration, analysing and reporting using Pentaho.
So at last, I needed to do some reporting using Pentaho tools. The problem that is our data is so big, so the reporting platform was too slow and the fact that we have so much lines, it stop responding from time to time and get reaaally slow.
Is there any solution to this ? A reporting tool or platform that we can use instead of Pentaho reporting without having to change the whole thing and get from the first ETL steps.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 alternatives:

1. Pay for Enterprise Edition (I'm not pentaho related :P)
2. Pre-process the data you are gonna show in the result report.

Remember that you can use PDI (Pentaho Spoon, Kettle or whatever you like to call it) as report datasource. You can "pre-process" the result data and use report designer just for themeing purposes. A transformation in Kettle can run in parallel, and can be distributed, so, if you have a cluster, use a PDI datasource that distributes the "queries" with all your hardware. That could improve 800x the performance.

Other option is generate historical data in text files, and read them via PDI Datasource.

You have thousands of options using PDI. :D

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer i will try this and go back for you when i do

Comment: payment for enterprise version of pentaho will not solve performance troubles by itself, heh.

Comment: To be honest, I thought the same, until I started to test it, and not only the administration is improved, the overall performance seems to be better, well it's a paid version, must expect something better. But you are right @DzmitryPrakapenka

Comment: The Entreprise version has Interactive Report (PIR), which is based on the PRD but consumes much more resources. So you indeed have a add-on that increase the performance of the PRD. It is something nobody never notice, because when you can us the PIR, you just want to forget about the PRD.

Comment: You are right @AlainD, but I was not centering on PRD or PIR, I was meaning overall, but I think the best comment about it would be based on a test benchmark, and at the moment, I just have my experience and not enough hardware to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer takes one word: if the data is big, then it is for PDI.

Preprocess the data and drop the result in the Pentaho Reporting Output. The drawback is that you cannot design a report with that method. You should first extract a small subset of the data to design the report.

Comment: The Pentaho Reporting output will generate a report in the flow of the transformation execution. But, the reports are actually developed, this solution forces to remake all the report execution (imagine it he is calling the reports via REST URL,  this will break all the entire scheme). That's why I suggested to just use a Data Integration Datasource on the report, and not changing all the report generation scheme, the report templates remaing intact, and will focus only on data generation scheme.

Comment: And in the question is not specified all the scenario, the op just mention "number of lines", but most of the problems with reporting on pentaho come to design (when is related to Pentaho Report Designer CE). Just use a subreport and you will be playing hangman game. Use dinamically heights on blocks with bands and reports, and even having less than 100 records, it will hang. That's my experience my friend.

Comment: Maybe we present solutions to the user, and he/she choose the answer. No need to cross bridges before to arrive to the water. Especially regarding [SOF comments best practice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50444/comments-dont-have-formatting-tags-or-line-breaks).